# How can I store pairs of numbers in a List and still be able to sort them and binary search them based on the first element?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

Basically I need to be able to sort and binary search based on the first number, but I also need to associate a second number to each element.

I can't do key value pairs, because the keys aren't necessarily unique. But I feel like this has to be common enough to warrant some kind of built in solution, like Pairs or something, only I don't know how to make them still sort based on the first int in a pair.

Any ideas?

Edit:

Per your suggestions, I pushed through with my face and just made this:

```
public class Pair
{
    int first;
    int second;
    public Pair(int x, int y)
    {
        first = x;
        second = y;
    }
    public int CompareTo(Pair compair)
    {
        if (compair != null)
        {
            return this.first.CompareTo(compair.first);
        }
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

I was really hoping there'd be something one line and built in, for speed if I need to do this in some kind of interview, but I guess it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated, and as you've started, you can create a `Pair` class that compares as you have it. But this requirement throws a monkey wrench into the works:

> I can't do key value pairs, because the keys aren't necessarily
>   unique.

So this tells me you can have multiple pairs with the same value for `first`. You can declare your `Pair` class as it is and then use a `SortedDictionary` based on that key. They will be sorted upon entry and you can perform an O(1) hashtable lookup:

```
var input = new[]{
    new Pair(1, 1),
    new Pair(5, 2),
    new Pair(1, 2),
    new Pair(2, 1),
    new Pair(7, 4),
    new Pair(3, 1),
    new Pair(7, 2)
};

SortedDictionary<int, List<Pair>> pairs = 
    new SortedDictionary<int, List<Pair>>();

foreach(var pair in input)
{
    if (!pairs.ContainsKey(pair.First))
        pairs.Add(pair.First, new List<Pair>());

    pairs[pair.First].Add(pair);
}
```

For completeness, here is the `Pair` class as I have declared it:

```
public class Pair : IComparable<Pair>
{
    public int First { get; private set; }
    public int Second { get; private set; }

    public Pair(int first, int second)
    {
        this.First = first;
        this.Second = second;
    }

    public int CompareTo(Pair other)
    {
        if (other != null)
            return this.First.CompareTo(other.First);
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

This is likely the route I would go (more or less depending on exact requirements). You also state:

> I was really hoping there'd be something one line and built in

Well, closest to "built-in" I can think of is using `Tuple<int, int>` and using a bit of LINQ. I've written it in two lines for clarity, but it can be easily combined into one line:

```
var input = new[]{
    Tuple.Create(1, 1),
    Tuple.Create(5, 2),
    Tuple.Create(1, 2),
    Tuple.Create(2, 1),
    Tuple.Create(7, 4),
    Tuple.Create(3, 1),
    Tuple.Create(7, 2)
};

var unsortedDictionary = input
    .GroupBy(p => p.Item1)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(i => i));

var sortedDictionary = 
    new SortedDictionary<int, IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>>>(unsortedDictionary);
```

I'm not sure if this is any better though. Kind of weird with the nested tuple there. If you want, the tuple becomes redundant at this point since the "Key" for the dictionary is duplicated with every value, so instead you can have a "Key" associated with a set of "Second" values (the second half of each pair):

```
var unsortedDictionary = input
    .GroupBy(p => p.Item1)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(i => i.Item2));

var sortedDictionary = 
    new SortedDictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>>(unsortedDictionary);
```

As for use in a job interview setting for speed, you may have to be careful. It's very easy to mix up types here (for example, very easy to pass an `IEnumerable<int>` when you meant to pass just `int` and misdeclare the type of the dictionaries and whatnot)

Comment: I don't think I'd ever want to trust myself to write that on a whiteboard without making ten thousand mistakes. 

Relatedly, the pair solution I did gets the job done I think.

Comment: @NathanTempelman Yes your solution works but the binary search returns an arbitrary row.

Comment: @NathanTempelman: Regarding binary search on the first number, it's not necessary with a dictionary lookup. Simply use the `.ContainsKey` method and lookup the entry; it's faster. Otherwise we're talking about some pretty contrived requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Create Class that hold 2 points, implement the [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.compareto%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Tuple<int,int>>
```

then the first number does not have to be unique